# Tomcat 7, writing aborted NotSerializableException on Serialized class

Tags: java, tomcat

I keep getting an IO exception in my catalina.out as in the stacktrace below. It is important to mention that

1. This only happens when running the server in a production environment. Running locally through MyEclipse doesn't give this error
2. The class name is actually Header.java, I don't know why the stacktrace is showing it to be Header$1
3. The Header.java class implements Serializable and extends the GenericForwardComposer

   ```
   WARNING: Cannot serialize session attribute org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.eventQueues for session 801CDDA59E689504D5CAA6513392A9E2        
   SEVERE: IOException while loading persisted sessions: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: mvc.publi.template.lbnew.Header$1 java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: mvc.publi.template.lbnew.Header$1
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1352)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
       at java.util.LinkedList.readObject(LinkedList.java:1136)
       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
       at java.util.LinkedList.readObject(LinkedList.java:1136)
       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:499)
       at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.DesktopImpl.readObject(DesktopImpl.java:1064)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
       at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1154)
       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1913)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
       at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1155)
       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1600)
       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:1073)
       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:284)
       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:204)
       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:470)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:633)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:558)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:468)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1329)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:389)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:334)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:621)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456) Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: mvc.publi.template.lbnew.Header$1
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
       at java.util.LinkedList.writeObject(LinkedList.java:1118)
       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor976.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
       at java.util.LinkedList.writeObject(LinkedList.java:1118)
       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor976.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:438)
       at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.DesktopImpl.writeObject(DesktopImpl.java:1027)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
       at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1099)
       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor973.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
       at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1100)
       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor973.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1676)
       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:1090)
       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:411)
       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:353)
       at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stopInternal(StandardManager.java:497)
       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:230)
       at         org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$4.run(StandardContext.java:5465)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
   ```

The Header.java class is

```
    public class Header extends GenericForwardComposer<Component> implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7964938307380973455L;

        private transient EventQueue<Event> queueApplication;
    private transient EventQueue<Event> queueSession;

        //other variable declarations

        public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {
    super.doAfterCompose(comp);

    EventListener<Event> applicationListener = new EventListener<Event>() {
         public void onEvent(Event evt) throws Exception {
                              //Some event handling here
                     }
            }

            queueApplication = EventQueues.lookup("groupApplication",EventQueues.APPLICATION,true);
    queueApplication.subscribe(applicationListener);

            EventListener<Event> applicationListener2 = new EventListener<Event>() {
        public void onEvent(Event evt) {
                             //Some event handling here
                     }
            }

            queueSession = EventQueues.lookup("groupSession", EventQueues.SESSION, true);   
    queueSession.subscribe(applicationListener2);

            //some code

            for (int i=0; i< supportedLangs.length; i++) {
        final Languages lang = supportedLangs[i];

        Image flag = new Image(Main.ICON_SERVER+"/public/template/" + skin.getFolder() + "/gfx/flags/" + supportedLangs[i].getImageName());
        flag.setId(supportedLangs[i].getLowercase());

        //create and register event listener
        EventListener<Event> actionListener = new SerializableEventListener<Event>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
                setLanguage(lang.getLowercase());
            }
        };

        flag.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLICK, actionListener);

        flags.appendChild(flag);
        flags.appendChild(new Label(" "));
    }

        //some more code
        }

        //Some other code
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the code for `mvc.publi.template.lbnew.Header`?

Comment: Please make sure, that all fields of your `Header` class also implement `Serializable` interface

Comment: What part of 'java.io.NotSerializableException: mvc.publi.template.lbnew.Header$1' don't you understand?

Comment: @EJP i don't understand why the stacktrace shows Header$1 but my java class is called Header, why is it appending the $1? Also the class does implement serializable so really not sure why I am still getting this exception.

Comment: @n1ckolas what do you mean by all the fields please? Isn't it enough to implement Serializable on the class?

Comment: @WillKeeling the Header has been added, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`$1` means an anonymous class inside your Header class. Make sure all classes, whose instances are assigned to members of classes, that are stored in the HTTP sesssion, are also serializable. In the case of anonymous classes you'd better have them `transient`.

In this case it might be `applicationListener` (make it lower-case), that you probably assigned to a variable of the class. Make the variable `transient`.

Comment: I've read that Serialization of an anonymous class is highly discouraged. Is there a better way to do this please?

Comment: I added a comment - use `transient`

Comment: I am still getting the errors although I've made the variables transient as you advised. I have edited my original post to add more info regarding the Header class including the transient variables.

Comment: can you show us your other global vars?